Activate Crystal Reports in VS22
Im new to Crystal Reports for VS.
I have installed the CR for Visual Studio SP35 64bit installer (VS 2022 and above) for Visual Studio Pro. 2022.
When I am in a existing project, I cannot find a way to drag it into my form from the Toolbox.
When I create a new project it works.
I can open and edit RPT files directly in Visual Studio.
I copied the templates from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\IDE' to 'C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2022\Templates'.
